# PHP while + if statements problem

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I have this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $number1=$row["number"];
    if (!empty($number1)) {
        // A few things happen here using if statements aswell but its fine
    }

    if (empty($number1)) {
        // A few things happen here using if statements aswell but its fine
    } 
}
```

For some reason, the data is there but it isn't working. No errors emerge at all and it then redirects to the page I want it to redirect to.

Comment: Please describe what is not working. You mention that there are no errors, and it redirects to a page as intended. This sounds conflicting.

Comment: What does "but it isn't working" mean?

Comment: what if you do it like this: `if (!empty($row["number"])) {...} else {...}`

Comment: "it isn't working". What did you expect to happen, and how does it differ from what did happen? What data goes into this section of code? Can you make a minimal, complete testcase on ideone.com that exhibits the issue? These are basic requirements for anyone but you to know what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Idea #1 - post the entire code.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: @Eugene: That is equivalent to the existing code.

Comment: Like i said below, its supposed mail but it doesn't at all

Comment: "it's supposed mail"?! the code you've posted has no call to `mail()`

Comment: @Backslap: We don't want a dump of that entire behemoth. Post a _minimal, complete testcase_. [Here's how](http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml).

Comment: funny question:
- the data is there but it isn't working
- no errors emerge at all
- it redirects to the page I "want" it to redirect to

What else do you need mate? I don't see no issues

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) does more than you might think?

For example, `empty("0")` is `true`.

You might be better off with `if (strlen($number1) > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe empty is returning false on an item that you might expect to be true... (for example 0). See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

You should check (print out or whatever)

- Does `$number1` contain what you expect?
- Does `empty($number1)` behave as you expect?
- Does the code you didn't post behave as you expect if you run it out of context with placeholder data?

Comment: Good debugging steps. I approve.